# Redirect To A Custom Url Depending on Location on wordpress with parameters

Tags: wordpress, redirect, geolocation, location, geo

I need to redirect my store customers to another clone installation in a sub-directory.

For Example:
A US visitor can visit: ‘example.com/product’
When a Canadian visitor visits the same link, it should redirect to: ‘example.com/ca/product’

I have tried out a few geo redirection plugins but the issue is as follows:
The redirection goes to ‘example.com/ca’ and the ‘product’ part is left out.

Any fixes?

NOTE: I have a clone installation of ‘example.com’ on ‘example.com/ca’.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't need such a comprehensive multilingual plugin setup in my wordpress installation. So I have just used multi-site and added this to my htaccess file to redirect users to my 'irish' site based upon browser language config:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^ie [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !ie [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yoursite.com/ie [L,R=301]
```

I hope this is a quick and easy fix for someone. As I tried doing an action in functions.php and kept going around in circles for an hour!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the plugin WPML for multilanguge. With this plugin you can use the option redirect by language WPML > Languages > Redirection according to browser language. I have it set up like  this in a website of mine and it works fine.

If you want do it trought IP, you will need to add some more work. Im sending you info, I hope it is useful for you:

1. https://wpml.org/forums/topic/autoselect-native-language/#post-284007
2. http://wordpress.org/plugins/geographical-redirect/
3. https://wpml.org/forums/topic/how-to-detect-ip-location-and-automatically-display-local-language/

Comment: Hey Thanks! Will definitely try this out and let you know.